# Configuring IIS application pool settings using PowerShell

Tags: powershell, iis

I'm trying to set the value of Enable32BitApplication and LoadUserProfile of an IIS app pool to True using PowerShell by running the following Cmdlets:

```
(Get-IISAppPool -Name DefaultAppPool).enable32BitAppOnWin64 = $True
(Get-IISAppPool -Name DefaultAppPool).ProcessModel.LoadUserProfile = $True
```

When I retrieve these values using PowerShell, it looks like the Cmdlets have run successfully, but when I try to check it in the GUI, I can note that it did not work. That's why I tried to test the website of the application pool in action, and I figured out that these Cmdlets does not work. Can anyone help me with the right PowerShell Cmdlets?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/iisadministration/stop-iiscommitdelay?view=win10-ps If you don't commit changes, not surprised.

Comment: Even when I commit, it does not work

Answer (score 7):

In order for it to work by modifying the object returned by `Get-IISAppPool` you have to call `Start-IISCommitDelay` prior to changing the values and then `Stop-IISCommitDelay` after making the changes. So in your case it'd be:

```
Start-IISCommitDelay
(Get-IISAppPool -Name DefaultAppPool).enable32BitAppOnWin64 = $True
(Get-IISAppPool -Name DefaultAppPool).ProcessModel.LoadUserProfile = $True
Stop-IISCommitDelay
```